# Problems installing Passenger Apache module with LAMPP (XAMPP for Linux)

Tags: passenger

On my Ubuntu system I have a LAMPP installation in /opt/lampp that works fine. I've installed passenger. Now I'd like to install the apache2 module for passenger:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

It couldn't find apache2 or the apache development headers. I installed everything missing accordingly as root and added environment variables as per [the passenger apache documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_forcing_location_of_certain_command_line_tools). However, they are obviously installed into general (system-wide) locations, e.g. /usr/bin, and not into the LAMPP installation.

When I run the above command again it finds all the apache dependencies, however the installation still fails to find a development header:

```
ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c:25:19: fatal error: httpd.h: No such file or directory
```

This file does not exist on my system, even though apache2 and LAMPP are installed. I tried to "fix" my apache installation with:

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2.2-common
```

but this did not restore httpd.h. I feel that I'm going about this the wrong way - should I be using a different version of LAMPP (one with an apache with development headers, for example?) or is my Ubuntu apache installation incomplete/corrupt? I got it to work with another system with only apache2 installed, but it seems like installing with LAMPP is problematic. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

httpd.h is in apache2-worker-dev or apache2-prefork-dev. In fact, the installer is supposed to give you that exact package name to enter into apt-get.

Comment: On Ubuntu it seems like apache2-prefork-dev is the one, and it does ask to install that, which I did, but there is no httpd.h on the filesystem.

Comment: Apparently the package has been renamed from apache2-worker-dev to apache2-threaded-dev these days. Anyway the file should be included in both apache2-prefork-dev and apache2-threaded-dev, as /usr/include/apache2/httpd.h.